# Realtek front panel audio detection not working?

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, speakers

My front panel on my computer isn't working at all. I know that I can simply fix this simply by Disable Front Panel jack on Realtek but that's going to tie up my Speaker and Headphone in one. I've checked all connections, updated all drivers. I want to have 2 different audio so I could choose either my Headphone or speaker. I used to do this 2 Years ago while I was running Windows 7 but after I formatted my computer I didn't needed that feature until now. So it's possible to Have two different streams, but Realtek not detecting my front panel.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found the following popup reading [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3zfyzm/windows_10_realtek_high_definition_audio_not/?st=ivk12bt7&sh=2647026d):

[image]

Click the folder icon to open it. Changing the setting here fixed it for me.

Comment: I've Clearly mentioned that this method doesn't work for what am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Old R2.82 driver is not working first you need to update the driver from this website:
[TenForum](https://www.tenforums.com/sound-audio/135259-latest-realtek-hd-audio-driver-version-2-a.html)

Then you need to Make from and rear output devices playback two different audio streams simultaneously in the Realtek Audio Manager
[image: Realtek Audio Manager]